# Which datum and projection to use?

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography

First sorry if I am incorrect in the words, I am using a translator to expose my doubt.

I have a requirement where I have a worldwide road base and my goal is to calculate the road network by country.

I know that it is impossible to do this calculation using only half a dozen "datums and projections", but I would like to know if there is a list of which EPSG to use by country or even by regions.
Here in Brazil we have the Brazilian Institute of Geography and Statistics - IBGE which suggests which EPSG to use for calculating the extension of linear elements (EPSG: 5880).
The big question is:
Is there any documentation where you can find a list of which EPSG to use for each region?
If we do not have it ready I believe that we are already late in creating a large repository where the best EPSG to use is listed.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and elaborate on what you want to calculate? Are you trying to calculate the total length of the road network within each country? Every projection has it's own unique errors, so changing projections is inherently going to cause "random" errors in your calculations.

Comment: Yes, I want to calculate the total length of the road network by country. The idea would be to do it by country, regions or locations. But for that I need an EPSG list.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if there is a list of which EPSG to use by country or even by regions.

You can search the *EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset* at http://www.epsg-registry.org/ to discover the EPSG codes for coordinate reference systems, projections, datums, areas etc.

Note the EPSG registry is in the process of being migrated to a new interface at:
https://epsg.org/home.html